# Will this singleton style class work with accessing a session on multiple MVC controllers?

Tags: mvc, singleton, static-access

**Question background:**

I have an e-commerce site I'm developing that requires multiple controller methods to access a single session variable.

**The idea:**

My idea was to create a singleton style class - lets call it `SessionChecker` that I would instantiate in the constructor of each controller, then call a method called `CheckSessionStatus();` this in turn would check to see if the session variable was null or not, if it is null then create a new session variable.

**Potential issue?**

I would **not** be creating the `SessionChecker` class as static, I would be creating a new instance in each controller. As a session can hold it's state and be accessed over multiple pages in the app would this be ok to do? i.e accessing the session state from a new instance of the `SessionChecker` class? **Or** would I be better off with a single static `SessionChecker` class that can be just accessed from each controller constructor?

Comment: What language are you using? What session management facilities does it already include?

Comment: `I would be creating a new instance in each controller.` -- That doesn't sound like a Singleton.  Perhaps you're thinking of a [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)?